# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir la consola en una label de Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, consola

¿Hay alguna forma de llamar a la consola para poder, en este caso, imprimir la consola en una **label** de tkinter?

He intentado algo como esto:

`label = Label(text=console.info)`

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo pasarte por [tour] y [ask] para conocer por encima el funcionamiento del sitio y cómo hacer buenas preguntas, ¿A qué te refieres exactamente con "imprimir la consola"? ¿A mostrar  la salida de algún subproceso por stdin en el Label? Agrega un poco más de contxeto sobre lo que haces y esperas conseguir.

Comment: @FJSevilla A eso me refiero, mostrar la salida en una label

Comment: ¿Usas subprocess o como llamas al proceso externo? ¿Cómo lo lanzas desde la GUI? ¿al pulsar un botón?, etc Intenta agregar un [mcve] para tener algo de más contexto,  incluso el sistema operativo puede ser relevante (por la codificación de la terminal).

Comment: @FJSevilla Un subprocess de la OS windows